# Scrapy: How to change the location of images stored using imagepiples for different spiders?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a Scrapy project with 5 spiders and every spider scrapes images and store it in the directory whose path is specified in **settings.py**. But i want to store these images in different locations for different spiders. Is there a way to specify paths within the spider?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`custom_settings`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider) to define settings for a spider:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    custom_settings = {
        'IMAGES_STORE': 'your_path',
    }
```